# Is the S is open?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

let $$S =\left \{ \frac 1{3^n} + \frac 1{7^m} |n,m ∈ \mathbb N \right \}$$. then which of the following statement is are true ?

(a) S is closed
(b) S is not open
(c) S is connected
(d) o  is a limit point of S .

my attempt  : option D is clearly true 0 is  a limit point. option(a)  is not true because 0  is not  contain in the set S and option (b) is not true,,as S is an open set . and option (c) is not true because $\frac{1}{3^{n}}$ is of the form rational number  as rational number is not connected ..

Is my answer is correct or not  and pliz verified and tell me the solution...i would be more thankful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> option D is clearly true 0 is a limit point.

You're right, but whether it's "clearly true" is perhaps a matter of judgment. Assuming that this is something for a class, you may well need to *prove* that result. (But again, you are correct.)

> option(a) is not true because 0 is not contain in the set S

Correct.

> option (b) is not true,,as S is an open set .

I disagree with your assessment that $S$ is open. Note that $1/3$ is in the set, for instance, but that there is no interval $(a,b)$ such that $1/3 \in (a,b)$ and $(a, b) \subset S$.

> and option (c) is not true because $\frac 1 {3^n}$ is of the form rational number as rational number is not connected ..

You're right that (c) is false, but I don't know that I see a good argument for it in what you've written. I recommend returning to the definition of a connected set and showing that it is not fulfilled here.

Comment: @ Aaron Montgomery     im not getting ur option B)....see that  there is no interval (a,b)  such that $\frac{1}{3}$..as  S is open set as it has limit point,,,,

Comment: if i take (0,1) then $\frac{1}{3}$  is  contain in (0,1)  where (0,1)  is an open interval

Comment: pliz tell  and  elaborate@Aaron Montgomery

Comment: But $(0,1)$ is not *a subset* of set $S$. For instance, $\pi/6 \in (0,1)$, but $\pi/6 \not \in S$. Here's an equivalent way to see that $S$ is not open: recall that $S$ is open iff $S^c$ is closed. I claim that $S^c$ is not closed, because $1/3$ is a limit point of $S^c$ but $1/3 \not \in S^c$.

Comment: thanks a lots @ Aaron Montgomery

Comment: To the proposer: Every non-empty real interval contains irrationals (and rationals also). So any non-empty set of only rationals or only irrationals cannot be open.

Comment: thanks @DanielWainfleet